# Is there a definition of nodejs buffer content size?

Tags: node.js, buffer

First I initialize a buffer object:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(10); // allocate it with 10 bytes
buffer.fill(0); // avoid sensitive data
buffer.write("abc")
console.log(buffer)
```

Maybe I can recognize its content length is 3, I conclude a buffer's content length equals to the index of a `00` byte after which every byte must be `00` :

```
<Buffer 61 62 63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
```

But if I do:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(10); // allocate it with 10 bytes
buffer.fill(0); // avoid sensitive data
for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
  buffer[i] = 0
}
console.log(buffer);
```

In this case, the buffer content length is whether 3 or 0?

```
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
```

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "content length", but the buffer's length, in both cases, is 10. Check this by doing `console.log(buffer.length)`